# How can I carry DC component to negative side?

Tags: analog, stm32, dc, dac

I made a sine wave with stm32f407VG DAC periphal. But my sine wave has DC component 1.32V. I designed high pass filter but DC component was gone. But I don't want it to be gone. How can I carry it to negative side?
[image]

Comment: @PrathikPrashanth I dont want it to be removed. I want to carry it to negative side. I want to move my sine wave to through -y axis.

Comment: Does your HPF have a negative power supply?

Comment: You added a HPF and noticed that the DC component was removed and were unhappy with the result. What did you think the HPF would do? Also, why have you added a power electronics tag? This is not related to power electronics. Please remove the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I carry it to negative side?

Assuming that you mean 'How can I add a negative offset to the sine wave', this is my solution:

[image]

The 100n capacitor is use for DC blocking and the two 10k resistors are used to bias the signal to -2.5V, so it will swing around that point. You can change the DC offset by changing the resistor values.